# Firebase on Android - how to make event handler for data retrieval fire when I need it to?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Firebase and need some help with a query to retrieve data from a table. I am currently able to access and retrieve the data that I need from firebase, however, the timing is the problem I am having an issue with.

From everything I've seen, the firebase database requires me to add event listeners to the Query or DatabaseReference objects. I am trying to download the contents of a node called "questions" before a method to display the question contents is called, however, I cannot control the timing of the firing of the event which downloads the data, and as a result my display method is always called before the firebase event fires.

How can I execute a query when I want, and be sure it will be completed before a certain section of my code executes? I am used to traditional RDBs where you execute a query and get its results and then move forward with your logic. The need to use an event handler with firebase is what I am having a hard time with. I have even tried moving the definition of the firebase reference object and the event handler into onCreate() and moved the code that calls my display method into onStart() without any success - same problem. The data I am trying to get does not change so I only need to download it once at the beginning to have available for the display method.

Here is an image of my "questions" node which is a child of the root.
image of the child "questions" node on my firebase DB

[image]

Here is my code:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Get Firebase DB reference
    firebase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    fdbRef = firebase.getReference("questions");

    // [START Question_event_listener]
    fdbRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Get Questions object and use the values to update the UI
            objQuestions = dataSnapshot.getValue();
            Log.w("Firebase:", "In Firebase ValueEventListener");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // Getting Questions failed, log a message
            Log.w("Firebase Error:", "onCancelled:", databaseError.toException());
            Toast.makeText(ReviewActivity.this, "Failed to load question!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    //. . . remaining onCreate logic removed for simplicity
} //end of onCreate

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // I moved this logic from onCreate to onStart but did not help...
    // Firebase retrieve must execute before I call any of these
    if (list_type == MainActivity.LIST_UNREVIEWED_DOCS)
        displayNewReviewForm();
    else if (list_type == MainActivity.LIST_REVIEWS)
        displayCompletedReview();
    else // (list_type == MainActivity.LIST_DRAFTS)
        displayDraftReview();
}
```

Other alternatives if I can't get this resolved may be to move this retrieve logic to the prior Activity in my sequence and pass the retrieved data as an extra to this activity - but that seems really silly to have to do such a thing. I would think I should be able to get data from a DB when I need it... not when it feels like giving it to me.

I appreciate any help getting me past this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at this a bit more, I came up with 2 possible solutions to the problem I had.

1. The first one I sort of mentioned already in my original question post, however it's not ideal in my opinion. It basically involves relocating the firebase retrieve logic to the prior Android Activity and passing the retrieved data to the Activity I need it in as an Extra. In my case the data is a HashMap so I would need to use the serialize versions of the methods to pass the serialized content to the desired Activity.
2. The best solution, is much simpler. I basically relocated the logic that I had in the onStart() function (which is calling my custom display methods) and moved it inside of the Firebase Event Listener's onDataChange() method, right after the call to dataSnapshot.getValue().  This ensures that I get the data before I call my display methods. This seems to be working well now.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is downloading the snapshot data containing all the data at the first go only, and with Firebase, you cannot download data timely, you can only do it through different references.

What I would suggest you to do is, to have a DatabaseReference of q01, q02 respectively and then call data as in when required.

If your Keys "q01", "q02" are static, which they are looking at the scenario. I would suggest you to have their DatabaseReferences:

```
question_one = firebase.getReference("q01");
question_two = firebase.getReference("q02");
question_three = firebase.getReference("q03");


//Once you have the reference, you can call their ValueListeners respectively
question_one.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // Get Questions object and use the values to update the UI
        objQuestions = dataSnapshot.getValue();
        Log.w("Firebase:", "In Firebase ValueEventListener");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting Questions failed, log a message
        Log.w("Firebase Error:", "onCancelled:", databaseError.toException());
        Toast.makeText(ReviewActivity.this, "Failed to load question!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Tanishq - I have about 20 different q## nodes below /questions path. I may add more as needed and they also have an "enabled" property to allow me to enable/disable them as needed. So statically coding for 20 fixed references does not sound like it would suit my needs. More importantly, I don't understand how creating the reference one layer down as you suggest would eliminate the problem of Firebase not firing the query or retrieval when I need it to (i.e. before the display logic occurs). Seems like I would have the same problem in the end. Am I missing something?

Comment: The only difference it would create by having a layer down is that it will not download all the data. When you call listener on a fixed reference, it downloads everything that is a child to it. So, at the first instance when you are initializing the listener, it is downloading every child node along with its data.

Comment: I'm aware of Firebase's best-practices for structure & how it downloads everything below the Ref point. I specifically structured my questions data to not be deep. I don't think structure or my reference point is the issue though. It's the timing of retrieval. In my case, android is calling the Activity's onCreate which contains my Firebase Ref & event logic, then it's calling the onStart, which then calls my display method to populate a custom adapter & displays data contents in listview. However Firebase doesn't actually initiate the retrieval until after I have displayed the empty listview.

Comment: I really can't believe I'm the first guy to run into this problem. What is the `Firebase equivalent of your typical database query scenario...                               ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
while(rs.next()) {
         //boom - you got your data. . .
}`